# Clang LLVM C++ `std::optional<std::optional<int>>` surprising comparison behavior

Tags: c++, c++17, clang++

I have a function `load(std::optional<int> page)` that either loads a given page, or all pages, if `page.empty()`. Because loading is a costly operation I cache the last loaded page and its contents. For that I'm using a member variable of type `std::optional<std::optional<int>>` whose value should tell me whether a single page, all pages or no pages at all are currently cached.

LLVM's libc++ implementation (shipped with clang `Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.2)`) has a surprising behavior when it comes to the comparison of std::optional instances, which is different from what `boost::optional` does (tested with 1.67):

```
std::cout << (std::optional<int>() == std::optional<std::optional<int>>()); // prints 1
std::cout << (boost::optional<int>() == boost::optional<boost::optional<int>>()); // prints 0
```

Which is the correct behavior and is this a bug in libc++'s implementation?

Comment: Whatever the outcome of this question, please *please* take your code to [codereview.se] so they can talk you out of `optional<optional<int>>`.

Comment: @Snetfel I laughed so hard right now :D

Comment: My guess is that LLVM is right. [Constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) Constructs an object that *does not contain a value*. And [`operator !=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_cmp) says that optionals, that *do not have a value* are considered equal.

Comment: @Sneftel Yes, that was my point, sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior is correct:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_cmp

> ```
> template< class T, class U > 
> constexpr bool operator!=( const optional<T>& lhs, const optional<U>& rhs ); (2)
> ```
>
> Performs comparison operations on optional objects.
>
> 1-6) Compares two optional objects, lhs and rhs. The contained values
>   are compared (using the corresponding operator of T) only if both lhs
>   and rhs contain values. Otherwise,
>
> - lhs is considered equal to rhs if, and only if, both lhs and rhs do
>     not contain a value.

The default constructor for `std::optional<T>` constructs an object that does not contain a value so both `std::optional<int>>()` and `std::optional<std::optional<int>>()` don't contain a value so they are equal.

Comment: If you want standard to cite standard in the answer, feel free to do so. [Constructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional.ctor#1), [Comparism](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional.relops#5), [Conversion](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional.observe#11)

Answer (score 3):

As a side note (but since we are here anyway) I personally am not too fond your design. As a consumer of your code I would expect `load(<empty optional>)` to load ... no page. That's what optional should mean.

One solution is to have two different functions:

```
void load(int);
void load_all();
```

If that seems too radical for you, then you can do overloads several ways:

```
struct load_all{};

void load(int);
void load(load_all);
```

I really like being explicit about what I request and what I get. That's why I strongly prefer the above to the next solution:

```
void load(int);
void load();
```

For completeness, although I wouldn't actually recommend it (because the tools to work with `std::variant` are cumbersome, otherwise this expresses the intent very well):

```
struct load_all{};

void load(std::variant<int, load_all>);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite interesting... the behavior is kind if ambiguous. There's no clear answer for what the comparison *should* do. And based on implementation choices, the standard library and Boost just do different things. Nobody is wrong.

`std::optional` has mixed comparisons. Meaning that there are operators comparing an `optional<T>`to an `optional<U>`and to a `U`. In this model, the best match is to treat both sides as *optional* -  and hence they compare equal because they're both disengaged.

But `boost::optional` only has same type comparisons. Meaning that `optional<T>` is only comparable to `optional<T>` or `T`. In this model, `optional<int>`is interpreted as a *value* of `optional<optional<int>>`. So we have a disengaged optional and a value - so they compare unequal.

I'm not sure this comparison actually has a clear meaning, so it's best to avoid it.